# Passing results from a MySQL query through to a PHP session login

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fix a login system from a friend's older project, and I can't seem to get it to accept a legitimate login, instead of going and passing the user's name and ID from the DB through, it just throws the error, even when it can get the correct username and ID from the DB. Any idea if it's this part of the code causing the error and what the solution is?

**MySQL Query and PHP Session**

```
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr="{.$_POST[username]}" AND pass="{.$_POST[password]}"'));
if($row['usr'])
{
    $_SESSION['usr'] = $row['usr'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];
}
else {
    //(display error message)
}
?>
```

**Login Form**

```
<form>
    <label class="grey" for="username">Username:</label>
    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
    <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="password" size="23" />
    <label><input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
</form>
```

**Full code**

http://pastebin.com/kj6i9Y8h

Comment: is your password encrypted in db?

Comment: Hi, firstly NEVER use sanitised inputs. I refer here to your direct use of $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password']. It is becoming common practice now to use parameterized SQL. It may also be worth looking into a Database Abstraction Layer such as doctrine as you will benefit from the research of highly knowledgeable people and the security they implement.
Anyway, What happens when you run that SQL query in PHPMyAdmin? Does it return anything? Also, what if you var_dump mysqli num_rows?

Comment: @mith Currently no, just for testing purposes. Will be done at a later date.

Comment: Hello @Fortera What error you recieve ?

Comment: @MichaelThompson Thanks for the heads up on that, another thing for me to look into.

Running the query gives me the ID and Name. var_dump gives me NULL.

Comment: @Fortera My apologies I accidentally pressed enter instead of single quote mark.
You should always sanitise anything that comes from the user. Anything from the user is untrusted input and can be modified by the browser or otherwise client. The following link explains which variables are external inputs. These are all untrusted inputs.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: @NavjotSingh The error is the one programmed to display when the username and password do not exist, not a PHP error

Comment: Can you run any other commands on the database from inside PHP? Also, have you got any error catching in place for determining when you can't connect to the database? I have had some weird problems sometimes where I cannot authenticate to the database even when all the information appears correct, and re-creating the user in phpmyadmin has resolved the issue.

Comment: @MichaelThompson I can interact with another table no problem, using another page that doesn't require authorisation to access.

Comment: @Fortera What is the result when you echo out the SQL string in your query?

Comment: @MichaelThompson If you mean the result of the query, it's giving me NULL.

Comment: @Fortera try adding `session_start();` after `if($row['usr'])
{`

Comment: @mwweb This didn't work as it is skipping that section due to the if/else.

Comment: @Fortera put it on top of the page. you need to start the session.

Comment: @mwweb It already is at the start.

Comment: @Fortera i dont see it in your code

Comment: @Fortera play around with this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm

Comment: @Fortera can you please print your query like this.

echo 'SELECT "id", "usr" FROM "tz_members" WHERE usr="'.$_POST['username'].'" AND pass="'.$_POST['password'].'"';

and run in the phpmyadmin to check

Comment: @mwweb I only included the parts that aren't working. I had a look at that site, but the issue is that the code isn't giving me any data from the table.

Comment: @NavjotSingh What do you mean? I can't run that in PHPMyAdmin, that's the PHP code with echo at the start, it won't do anything.

Comment: What hapens when you can mysqli errno after your query? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php    you should load that into a variable and then fetch assoc that variable, check the errno immediately after the query.

Comment: @Fortera I say first print this in your code and after that copy the print sql statement and paste in the phpmyadmin and then run this

Comment: @MichaelThompson response is NULL

Comment: @NavjotSingh I get it now, it's not receiving the username and password from the form.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps :)

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT "id", "usr" FROM "tz_members" WHERE usr="'.$_POST['username'].'" AND pass="'.$_POST['password'].'"'));
```

Comment: Sadly, didn't work. Still got NULL for mysqli_num_rows.

Comment: You can try `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT id, usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='.$_POST['username'].' AND pass='.$_POST['password'].''));` and if you get NULL then there is no way that username and pass are matching in this table tz_members (invalid username or pass?), or you have invalid $con?

Comment: $con is correct as I can read and alter the contents of a table that doesn't reqire me to login, and the username and password are correct as putting them into PHPMyAdmin directly with the query used gives the correct result.